# Did our instructor cross the line by complaining about our evaluations of him and what to do?

Tags: professionalism, communication, training

I was in a job-training course, where my company flew in an instructor  from another company. It was a compressed course. Afterwards, all of us evaluated the instructor  online(about 15 students).

Well, the instructor met us again the day after the course was concluded. We were to have one more course with him, a one-day course this time.

However, at the start of day , said instructor complained about negative feedback that he received. Somethin to the extent that "Oh I didn't complain to *your* managers that some of you were on email or whatever " and also that we were potentially cutting into his "livelihood".

afterward, I felt troubled about this. Here is an instructor who was *hired* by my company, aand is complaining about a routine administrative task. Which is.. feedback!

I feel hurt about it - is it professional for our instructor to have complained in this way, and should I discuss his complaints at my workplace?

Comment: What is your question? This sounds more like you wanting validation rather than an actual question.

Comment: Sounds like he wants to get even more negative feedback, carrying on like that...

Comment: I think there is a valid question in there: "what to do when an external instructor shows sub-par performance". The answer is simple: Bring this to the attention of whomever hired this guy and make sure he never gets hired again. Someone who can't accept feedback doesn't seem like a suitable instructor to me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is your complaint about the course?

Comment: I think Hilmar is right, what the asker wanted seemed clear enough to me although the question could be cleaned up a bit. "Is it acceptable to give negative feedback about an instructor and what should I do if the instructor complains about this?"